# AngularJs modal button ok and cancel not working

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal) on click of edit button using a modal service. But whenever I click modal cancel or ok button it does not work. I tried searching for different ways to make it work but could not find any with recent angularjs versions.

Here's the project link:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/tTbrAr9H78qS34Wl?open=modal-services.js&preview

Comment: Please clarify your question, I see no "OK" button just a "Submit".  To get effective answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you explain what "is does not work" mean? when i click the buttons the modal closes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `controllerAs: '$ctrl'`, and the `ok()` and `cancel()` methods are on `$ctrl`, not on the `$scope`. So the template needs to use `$ctrl.ok()`, not `ok()`.